# How do I set Azure Pipelines triggers on condition directly from the .yml file?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, triggers, yaml, azure-pipelines

I tried with

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      ${{ if flavour == 'staging' }}:
      - staging
      ${{ else }}:
      - master
```

But Azure returns the following error:

> /devops/build&upload.yml (Line: 4, Col: 7): A mapping was not expected

The result I want to achieve is to have triggers depending on the value of the *flavour* variable. It can be set to *staging*, in which case I want the value of *include* to be *staging*, or it can have other values, in which case I want the *include* to have the value *master*.

Comment: What you want to do? Question is not clear.

Comment: @Daredevil I want to set the value of "include" depending on the flavour of the app. I have that variable "flavour" that is either set to "staging", or other values. I want to set the trigger to include "staging" if the flavour variable is set to "staging", or to "master" if the "flavour" variable has any other value

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully make it clearer

Comment: Branches do not support conditions.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by flavor. As Mentioned by @ShamraiAleksander branches triggers do not support conditions. But you can possibly achieve something similar with Tags. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#tags

Comment: Flavours are like different environments for apps. A great explanation is given on the Flutter documentation -> https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Trigger blocks can't contain variables or template expressions.

You can check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64909614/14996050) for the details.

If you would triggers depending on the value of the flavour variable, as an alternative, you can:

1. Use `UI` trigger to override the yaml trigger, as if you use trigger in yaml, it could have different triggers defined between branches.

[image]

2. Use a **new** pipeline, determine the branch according to the variable flavour value, then use rest api to get the pipeline definition, and [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) the trigger to your expectation.

The `new` yaml sample:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  - name: flavour
    value: staging 

steps:
- ${{ if eq(variables.flavour, 'staging') }}:
  - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=branchToUse;]staging"
- ${{ else }}:
  - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=branchToUse;]main"

- powershell: |
    $Organization = "org"
    $Project = "project"
    $PipelineId = "pipelineid"
    $header = @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}

    $request = "https://dev.azure.com/$($Organization)/$($Project)/_apis/build/definitions/$($PipelineId)?api-version=7.1-preview.7"
    echo $request   # check the request url
    $json = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $request -Method Get -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json" | ConvertFrom-Json

    # Set Branch Filter
    $defaultBranch = "$(branchToUse)"
    $branchFilters = @("+refs/heads/$($defaultBranch)")

    $json.triggers[0].branchFilters = $branchFilters

    echo $json.triggers[0].branchFilters   # check the branch value

    # Convert PSObject back to Json
    $json = $json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

    # Update Pipeline
    $request = "https://dev.azure.com/$($Organization)/$($Project)/_apis/build/definitions/$($PipelineId)?api-version=7.1-preview.7"
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $request -Method Put -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header -Body $json
```

The branch updated:

[image]

[image]

Here i used `system.accestoken` in the rest api, please make sure on `target pipeline`, the `build service account` has `edit pipeline` permission otherwise the rest api will be denied.

[image]